# Get the max values from list result

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have the following results in employee table :

```
 ID | Name  | Number
---------------------
1   | Dani  |  15
2   | Dani  |  20
3   | Yara  |  10
```

I need to write sql query to get the following result:

```
ID | Name | Number
------------------
2  | Dani |   20  
3  | Yara |   10
```

as you see , if the result contained of the frequent name for the employee,the query must get the max value (number).

How i can do that?

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server and MySQL are very different.

Comment: I need it in SQL Server and Oracle please.

Comment: How about ties? Any line? Both lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you also want the correct id pointing to the maximum value, this is the easiest way:

```
WITH TT AS (
    SELECT ID, Name, Number, rank() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Number DESC) R
    FROM employee
)
SELECT ID, Name, Number
FROM TT
WHERE R = 1;
```

It should work correctly on Oracle and SQL Server as they both support window functions.

[SQLFiddle example using Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a88d/6)

Answer (score 1):

From the data set you provided you could simply use a `GROUP BY` clause. The syntax in the various engines you mentioned are all pretty similar.

In MySQL:

```
SELECT MAX(`ID`), `Name`, MAX(`Number`)
FROM `Employee`
GROUP BY `Name`
```

In T-SQL (SQL Server):

```
SELECT MAX([ID]), [Name], MAX([Number])
FROM [Employee]
GROUP BY [Name]
```

In Oracle:

```
SELECT MAX("ID"), "Name", MAX("Number")
FROM "Employee"
GROUP BY "Name"
```

Note that this independently calculates the maximum values of `ID` and `Number`. For example, if you had this data set:

```
ID - Name - Number
 1 - Dani - 20
 2 - Dani - 15
 3 - Yara - 10
```

You'd get this result:

```
ID - Name - Number
 2 - Dani - 20
 3 - Yara - 10
```

Notice that the `ID` for `Dani` is 2, since that's the maximum value of the `ID` column for `Dani`. If you'd like to get an `ID` of 1, you'd probably be better off using [*Vincent's* solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23417358/1715579).

Comment: This assumes the OP wants the maximum ID, which seems unlikely.

Comment: +1 it is always good to see simple yet efficient answers, why over-engineer when we can do it simple? :)

Comment: You're returning the max of each of those columns independently. I might be reading too much intent, but I think the poster is asking for the row with the max Number column

Comment: @Danny It's not entirely clear from the question. Actually from the description, it's not entirely clear if OP even cares about the `ID` column. If OP clarifies the question, I'd be happy to update.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - agree with you that it needs some clarity, but when they mention the "max number one" I'm taking them to mean they're looking for the max value in the column named "number".  I think if you flipped the `ID` in rows 1 & 2 then you'd get a different answer.

Comment: @Danny I was about to update when I noticed *Vincent* had already written almost exactly what I was working on.

Comment: @joe . . . This isn't a simpler answer.  It is a wrong answer to the question.

Comment: I need the record which contained of the max value from number if the result contained of the name frequent.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're right, only realized it after re-reading the entire post + some comments, to me it seemed to be ok to just get the biggest value groupped by name.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the maximum value for each name, and then join that back to the original table using `Name` and `Number` so that you can have access to all its values (like ID)

```
SELECT t.*
   FROM Employee e
   JOIN (SELECT Name, MAX(Number) AS Number
            FROM Employee e
            GROUP BY Name) maxnum ON maxnum.Number = e.Number AND maxnum.Name = e.Name
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go if your DBMS does not support window functions, such as MySQL. Only problem is when you want to select the top-n rows, where n > 1.

Comment: @VincentSavard Yeah, I like your answer better than mine for databases that support it, but I have to confess that this construction comes to my brain more easily. I think I need to use yours more often until it wears the proper neural path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, using `max` and the `group by` clause:

```
select max(t.ID)
     , t.Name
     , max(t.Number) 
from employee t
group by t.Name
```

Comment: Count is not the function you want here.