# Getting a single row based on unique column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I think this is mostly a terminology issue, where I'm having a hard time articulating a problem.

I've got a table with a couple columns that manage some historical log data. The two columns I'm interested in are timestamp(or Id, as the id is generated sequentially) and terminalID.

I'd like to supply a list of terminal ids and find only the latest data, that is highest id or  timestamp per terminalID

---

Ended up using group solution as @Danny suggested, and the other solution he referenced

I found the time difference to be quite noticeable, so I'm posting both results here for anyone's FYI.

## S1:

```
SELECT UR.* FROM(
SELECT TerminalID, MAX(ID) as lID 
    FROM dbo.Results
    WHERE TerminalID in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
    GROUP BY TerminalID
) GT left join dbo.Results UR on UR.id=lID
```

## S2

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT TOP 100
      Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY terminalID ORDER BY Id DESC) AS [Row], *
   FROM dbo.Results
   WHERE TerminalID in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
   ORDER BY Id DESC
) a
WHERE a.row=1
```

the results were:

S1:

- CPU time = 297 ms,  elapsed time = 343 ms.
- Query Cost 36%
- Missing index impact - 94%

S2:

- CPU time = 562 ms,  elapsed time = 1000 ms.
- Query Cost 64%
- Missing index impact - 41%

After adding the missing index to solution one (indexing ID only, as opposed to s2, where multiple columns needed an index), I got the query down to 15ms

Comment: Sounds like you just want to `Order By` and `Top 1` ?

Comment: It's best to provide examples for the data and expected output. Otherwise you get lots of guesses at answers. Based on your question, it sounds like you want to use row_number and use the partition by feature where row_number=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with `GROUP BY`.  Sounds like you want:

```
SELECT TerminalID, MAX(Timestamp) AS LastTimestamp
    FROM [Table_Name]
    WHERE TerminalID IN (.., .., .., ..)
    GROUP BY TerminalID
```

Comment: is there a way to get the other column data for the retrieved row? let's say I have a status column I want to display for the last row, grouping it will no longer work, because I get all statuses. Is it possible to get this without joining the grouped table with itself? (which is easy enough)

Comment: I would just join back on the grouped table on the TerminalID and LastTimestamp.  But I had a similar discussion with someone recently, and he has a pretty slick solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23417358/3063706

Comment: I did both - the join is significantly faster - adding info to question.

Answer (score 3):

use the `TOP` keyword:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, terminalID FROM MyTable WHERE <your condition> ORDER BY <something that orders it like you need so that the correct top row is returned>.
```

Comment: that works for one item only, when I use `in(144,145,156)` I only get one result

Comment: @Daniel -- That's because you said "find only the latest data, that is highest id or timestamp per terminalID" which indicates one result.  You may want to clarify your question, in that case.

Answer (score 1):

While not as obvious as using `MAX` with a `GROUP BY`, this can offer extra flexibility if you need to have more than one column determining which row or rows you want pulled back.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT
      Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY terminalID ORDER BY Id DESC) AS [Row],
      [terminalID],[Id],[timestamp]
   FROM <TABLE>
   ORDER BY Id DESC
) a
WHERE a.row=1
```